# MSSQL 2012 - Returning multiple columns in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'd like to return multiple columns with a sub query.

E.G,

```
select a.name, a.age
       from table1 a, ( select b.race, b.weight from table2 b where dateDiff(dd, b.date1, b.date2 ) < 30 )
where a.age > 24
```

Some of you have said "Just use a join" - I do not want the dateDiff in the subquery affecting the results of the parent query. Again, my real query is more complex then this but this should be sufficient in explaining my issue.

Comment: So why dont you use joins and get the required result?

Comment: Use joins rather than subquery

Comment: Please give more details about your subquery, so we can understand why you won't use a LEFT JOIN. With the current example, the answer given by Hip Hip Array is the correct one.

Comment: @Treb I just updated. Hopefully that helps explain. I do not want the dateDiff clause in my subquery to affect the parent results. Is it possible to do that in a left join?

Comment: Just put the dateDiff() condition into the `LEFT JOIN` condition.

Comment: It should not affect the result set of the outer query at all. If a LEFT JOIN doesn't find a match in the joined table (or, in this case subquery), the fields selected from it are filled with NULL values for this line. (BTW, in the new example you don't have any relation between table1 and table2 - but I assume that in the real query you actually have that, don't you?)

Comment: Can your subquery from `Table2` return more then 1 row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use left join to do this, left join will return NULL values

```
SELECT a.name, b.score, ...
FROM (select id, name, ... from table1 where ???) a
LEFT JOIN (select id, score, ... from table2 where ???) b on (a.id = b.id)
WHERE clause
```

Comment: I probably didn't explain my question well enough - but I cannot use a join in this case. As I have several conditions in my subquery which I do not want affecting my parent results.

Comment: @JasonWells - You should probably post your actual query than to put up a simple query and ask for an answer.

Comment: @JasonWells: You can still join on select statement, check my edit